# Math.min returning NaN for string argument

Tags: javascript, arrays

I created a Javascript function that successfully completes math operations involving two arrays. The `result` is: `1.7320508075688772,3.4641016151377544,5.196152422706632,` which I don't think is an array (right?). However, `Math.min(result)` returns `NaN` instead of *1.7320508075688772*.

Example below shows my troubleshooting efforts. The first alert is `result` (ok), then an alert for `Math.min` of the same value as a string (ok), then a third alert for `Math.min` of the variable (issue).

I assume I need to transform `results` value before passing to `Math.min(result)`.

I am a beginner and this is an learning exercise, so I am not interested in more efficient ways of executing what is already ok :)

```js
function calculate() {
  var array1 = [1, 1, 1];
  var array2 = [
    [2, 2, 2],
    [3, 3, 3],
    [4, 4, 4]
  ];
  var i = 0;
  var result = '';
  for (; i < array2.length; i++) {
    result += Math.sqrt(Math.pow((array1[0] - array2[i][0]), 2) + Math.pow((array1[1] - array2[i][1]), 2) + Math.pow((array1[2] - array2[i][2]), 2)) + ',';
  };
  alert(result);
  alert(Math.min(1.7320508075688772, 3.4641016151377544, 5.196152422706632, ));
  var minResult = Math.min(result);
  alert(minResult);

}
```

```html
<button onclick="calculate()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: `result` is a string, the arguments to `Math.min` have to be numbers.

Comment: Don't use alert for debugging. Open the browser's console and use `console.log()` to print the variables. In the console you'll see what type they are.

Comment: Why are you using a string for `result`? Put them in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Math.min()` requires the arguments to be numbers. It will convert strings to numbers, but each value needs to be in a separate argument -- it won't convert a comma-delimited string to multiple numbers.

Don't use a string for `result`, use an array. Then you can spread the array into function arguments.

```js
function calculate() {
  var array1 = [1, 1, 1];
  var array2 = [
    [2, 2, 2],
    [3, 3, 3],
    [4, 4, 4]
  ];
  var i = 0;
  var result = [];
  for (; i < array2.length; i++) {
    result.push(Math.sqrt(Math.pow((array1[0] - array2[i][0]), 2) + Math.pow((array1[1] - array2[i][1]), 2) + Math.pow((array1[2] - array2[i][2]), 2)));
  };
  console.log(result);
  console.log(Math.min(1.7320508075688772, 3.4641016151377544, 5.196152422706632, ));
  var minResult = Math.min(...result);
  console.log(minResult);

}
```

```html
<button onclick="calculate()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing as a param on `Math.min` a string

```
"1.7320508075688772,3.4641016151377544,5.196152422706632,"
```

You can split that string (not recommended)

```js
function calculate() {
  var array1 = [1, 1, 1];
  var array2 = [
    [2, 2, 2],
    [3, 3, 3],
    [4, 4, 4]
  ];
  var i = 0;
  var result = '';
  for (; i < array2.length; i++) {
    result += Math.sqrt(Math.pow((array1[0] - array2[i][0]), 2) + Math.pow((array1[1] - array2[i][1]), 2) + Math.pow((array1[2] - array2[i][2]), 2)) + ',';
  };
  console.log(result);
  console.log(Math.min(1.7320508075688772, 3.4641016151377544, 5.196152422706632, ));
  var minResult = Math.min.apply(null, result.split(",").filter(n => n.trim() !== "").map(Number));
  console.log(minResult);

}
```

```html
<button onclick="calculate()">Click me</button>
```

Or, add the numbers into an array and find the min value using the function `apply` as follow

```js
function calculate() {
  var array1 = [1, 1, 1];
  var array2 = [
    [2, 2, 2],
    [3, 3, 3],
    [4, 4, 4]
  ];
  var i = 0;
  var result = [];
  for (; i < array2.length; i++) {
    result.push(Math.sqrt(Math.pow((array1[0] - array2[i][0]), 2) + Math.pow((array1[1] - array2[i][1]), 2) + Math.pow((array1[2] - array2[i][2]), 2)));
  };
  console.log(result);
  console.log(Math.min(1.7320508075688772, 3.4641016151377544, 5.196152422706632, ));
  var minResult = Math.min.apply(null, result);
  console.log(minResult);

}
```

```html
<button onclick="calculate()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass numbers or arrays to the `Math.min()` function. You are passing a string and hence the error.

However, if you are just willing to pass string and somehow get answer, you can use the below answer (which isn't recommended as standard approach).

```js
function calculate() {
  var array1 = [1, 1, 1];
  var array2 = [
    [2, 2, 2],
    [3, 3, 3],
    [4, 4, 4]
  ];
  var i = 0;
  var result = '';
  for (; i < array2.length; i++) {
    result += Math.sqrt(Math.pow((array1[0] - array2[i][0]), 2) + Math.pow((array1[1] - array2[i][1]), 2) + Math.pow((array1[2] - array2[i][2]), 2)) + ',';
  };
  console.log(result);
  console.log(Math.min(1.7320508075688772, 3.4641016151377544, 5.196152422706632, ));

  //converting string to list
  arr = result.split(',').map(el => +el);
  arr.pop(); //to remove last 0 which will remain in the list due to last comma
  // spread operator to pass an array to the function
  var minResult = Math.min(...arr);

  console.log(arr);
  console.log(minResult);

}
```

```html
<button onclick="calculate()">Click me</button>
```

A better approach would be to maintain an array itself rather than having a string and converting it back to an array.

```js
function calculate() {
  var array1 = [1, 1, 1];
  var array2 = [
    [2, 2, 2],
    [3, 3, 3],
    [4, 4, 4]
  ];
  var i = 0;
  // maintaing an array rather than string
  var result = [];
  // pushing elements into the array
  for (; i < array2.length; i++) {
    result.push(Math.sqrt(Math.pow((array1[0] - array2[i][0]), 2) + Math.pow((array1[1] - array2[i][1]), 2) + Math.pow((array1[2] - array2[i][2]), 2)));
  };
  console.log(result);
  console.log(Math.min(1.7320508075688772, 3.4641016151377544, 5.196152422706632, ));
  // using spread operator to pass array elements as function args
  var minResult = Math.min(...result);
  console.log(minResult);

}
```

```html
<button onclick="calculate()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Math.min()` only takes numbers as arguments so convert your string result to an array of numbers and pass it to `Math.min()` using the spread operator.
change your line of code:

`var minResult = Math.min(result);`

to

`var minResult = Math.min(...result);`

and add this code block above that

```
// convert results string to an array of numbers
result = result.split(',').reduce((acc, c)=>{
    !isNaN(parseFloat(c)) && acc.push(parseFloat(c))
    return acc
}, []);
```

or go with an ugly one-liner ;)

<sup>`var minResult=Math.min(...result.split(',').reduce((a,c)=>(!isNaN(parseFloat(c))&&a.push(parseFloat(c)),a),[]));`</sup>